# How to get filename of the rendered font CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, jestjs, font-face, font-family

Is it possible to get the filename of the rendered font of an element?

Example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../../public/fonts/MyFont-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../../public/fonts/MyFont-Italic.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

.my-font-bold {
 font-family: 'MyFont';
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

`<p className="my-font-bold"></p>`

In this example I would like to get `../../public/fonts/MyFont-Bold.woff2` of the  element (because it has font-weight bold and font-family = "MyFont" thanks to the className "my-font-bold").

PS: I would like to do this to make font Vitest tests.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-flower-q87vz7?file=%2Fapp%2Ffont.test.tsx%3A27%2C2

Comment: So are you using `jsdom` or `testing-library`?I can help you with an helper function that does this task for you. Then I believe you can write the test for that helper function. Is my understanding of your requirement correct?

Comment: I use testing-library, yes you understood correctly

Comment: I don't think this is something you can get from DOM/jsdom. Your best bet would probably be to intercept requests somehow (probably mocking fetch won't work, maybe  MSW will be needed) and then assert which of two files was requested. Another approach is to use something like Cypress to render the page, take a screenshot, save it as a snapshot and then test that snapshot didn't change (hashsum or diff).

Comment: you confirm what I thought, I think the best approach is screenshot diff with Cypress

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript it is definitely possible. You just need to leverage the ***[`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)*** to achieve that.

**Steps to achieve the requirement:**

1. Get the font name of the font that `p` tag is using.
2. Get all the css rules associated with the document as an array.
3. Filter out the font-family based on ***step 1***.
4. If the fontFaceRule exists, extract the `url` and return the result else return `null`.
5. Post this you can write the test for this helper function in jest.

**Code implementation:**

```js
function getRenderedFontUrl(element) {
  const fontFamily = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('font-family').replace(/['"]/g, '');
  const cssRules = Array.from(document.styleSheets).flatMap(sheet => Array.from(sheet.cssRules));

  const fontFaceRule = cssRules.find(rule => {
    return rule.type === CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE && rule.style.getPropertyValue('font-family') === fontFamily;
  });
  

  if (fontFaceRule) {
    const src = fontFaceRule.style.getPropertyValue('src');
    const urlRegex = /url\((['"]?)(.*?)\1\)/g;
    const match = urlRegex.exec(src);
    return match ? match[2] : null;
  }

  return null;
}

// Usage example
const paragraphElement = document.querySelector('p');
const fontUrl = getRenderedFontUrl(paragraphElement);
console.log(fontUrl);
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../../public/fonts/MyFont-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../../public/fonts/MyFont-Italic.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

.my-font-bold {
 font-family: 'MyFont';
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family: 'MyFont'; font-weight: bold;">
```

**Writing the test for the above function:**

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import { getRenderedFontUrl } from './path-where-you-defined';

const { window } = new JSDOM();
global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;

describe('getRenderedFontUrl', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    document.head.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'MyFont';
          src: url('../../public/fonts/MyFont.woff2') format('woff2');
          font-weight: 300;
          font-style: normal;
        }

        p {
          font-family: 'MyFont';
        }
      </style>
    `;
  });

  it('should return font URL for an element with', () => {
    const pElement = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(pElement);

    const fontUrl = getRenderedFontUrl(pElement);
    expect(fontUrl).toBe('../../public/fonts/MyFont.woff2');
  });

  it('should return null for an element without', () => {
    const divElement = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(divElement);

    const fontUrl = getRenderedFontUrl(divElement);
    expect(fontUrl).toBeNull();
  });
});
```